# Powershell script that gives me any overview of several remote systems

Tags: powershell, csv, hardware, remote-access

So I am trying to get a script together that will give me an overview of several machines on our network. So far I have pieced together a few things, but still having trouble getting it to work. I would like to have a CSV file that has the following info:

**Asset / Computer Name** (Usually I need to use this for records)
**Offline / Online Status** (I can target just online machines)
**Current IP Address** (If name doesn't resolve right, can remote in using IP)
**Current Logged On User** (Insert N/A if no one logged on)
**OS Name** (To Find Older Windows 7 Machines)
**OS Version** (What needs updated to our Standards)
**Maybe Model** (This Might Be Helpful)
**Specific Software** (Like Adobe, WebEx, Etc)

If I can pull all this into an CSV and then save as an excel spreadsheet, this would help cut down time pulling this info from several other sources / software that I use. So far I have the following but some items are giving me issues.

```
# Source Text File For List of Computers
    Get-Content "listofcomputers.txt"  | ForEach-Object{

# Grab Current Status
    $pingstatus = ""
    if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $_ -Quiet) {
        $pingstatus = "Online"
    } else {
        $pingstatus = "Offline"
    }

# Grab Current IP Address
    $ip_address = (Test-Connection -ea stop -Count 1 -comp $_).IPV4Address).IPAddresstoString
    if (!$ip_address){
    $ip_address = "N/A"
    } 
    else{
    $ip_address = (Test-Connection -ea stop -Count 1 -comp $_).IPV4Address).IPAddresstoString
    }
            
# Grab OS Name & Version
    $os_name = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ ).Caption
    if(!$os_name){
    $os_name = "The machine is unavailable"
    $os_version = "N/A"
    }
    else{
    $os_version = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ ).Version 
    }

# Create Object Table
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    ComputerName = $_
    Status = $pingstatus
    Address = $ip_address
    OSName = $os_name
    OSVersion = $os_version 
    }} | Select ComputerName,Status,Address,OSName,OSVersion |

# Scan For Specific Software
    Get-WMIObject -Class win32_product -Filter {Name like "%Microsoft%"} -ComputerName $computers -ErrorAction STOP | Select-Object -Property Name,Version
}

# Export Results to CSV
    Export-Csv "z_queryresults.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Display Results Witin PS Window
    $P = Import-Csv -Path .\z_queryresults.csv
    $P | Format-Table
    
# Pause Script & Exit
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

Could anyone help me or direct me towards a similar script that would give me the end results I am looking for?

So to clarify, the end result would be similar to this:
[image]

Comment: seems like everyone does this. [*grin*] so here is mine ... >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH

Comment: Made some suggestions in my answer.  If you can be specific about the issues you're facing, we can offer some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Before you scrap this and use someone else's script, let me say that there is great value in doing it yourself and you're **so close to done!**

In fact, the only issue I see is this: if this is going to hit a LOT of PCs, don't query `Win32_Product` for software info.  Looking up against `Win32_Product` triggers Windows Installer to revaluate if the software is actually installed.  It generates a lot of Windows Event log messages and also is noticeably slow / may spin up CPU Fans.  In fact, it is so bad, a respected community member wrote this blog post about it: ["Win32_Product is Evil!"](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/)

If you've got ConfigurationManager installed on the devices, use `CCM_InstalledProduct` instead. If not, there are plenty of alternatives, but don't let this stop your progress.

Your script looks pretty promising, I would just invert the structure of the `ForEach-Object` and move it into a standalone `ForEach($item in $collection)` pattern loop.

And I'd add a tracking item per each item in the collection too.  Otherwise, it looks pretty good.

```
# Source Text File For List of Computers
    Get-Content "listofcomputers.txt"  | ForEach-Object{
```

Becomes...

```
# Source Text File For List of Computers
$computerList = Get-Content "listofcomputers.txt"  
ForEach($computer in $computerList){

#do all of your lookup stuff here
}
```

Any reference to `$_` should be replaced with `$computer`.

Next, at the bottom of the loop, I would generate a new object per each computer, like this `[psCustomObject]@{ColumnName=ColumnValue}`.  So to use some of those properties you retrieved, it would look like:

```
$computerList = Get-Content "listofcomputers.txt"  
ForEach($computer in $computerList){

#do all of your lookup stuff here...

#lookupstuff done, generate output object to show results

$thisComputer = [psCustomObject]@{
 ComputerName=$computer;
 IP =$ip_address;
 OnlineStatus = $pingStatus
 }

$thisComputer #show the output
}
```

From here, you would probably want to add each new output object to an array, and then send the whole array at once over to `Export-Csv`, and I think you'll find that much easier.

If you get stuck, post a new question and we'll get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

I like FoxDeploy's answer... however, I was in the middle of working on the script when he replied, so I still want to post for completeness sake. It includes a lot of the recommendations that Fox mentioned. One difference is handling the 'software' portion. I have several scripts that do this kind of thing, and for ease of sorting, you'll want to make sure that each bit of software is on its own line. The results of the below script are going to have several lines per PC. You can then use Excel to create a pivot table to better sort your info if you just want, for example, the names of the PCs.

In my experience, I find this yields the most usable results. The script below is quite a bit different from the script you'd originally written, but I hope it can make a good reference to tweak your own script.

```
# Source Text File For List of Computers
$PCs = Get-Content "listofcomputers.txt"

# Define the array that will hold your results
$results = @()

foreach ($pc in $pcs)
{
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        $ip = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).IPV4Address.IPAddresstoString
        $OS = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem}
        $software = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Microsoft%"' -Property Name,Version}
        foreach ($ware in $software)
        {
            
            $results += [pscustomobject]@{
                Name = $pc
                IP = $ip
                OSName = $os.Caption
                Version = $os.Version
                SoftwareName = $ware.Name
                SoftwareVersion = $ware.Version
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $results += [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $pc
            IP = "Offline"
            OSName = ""
            Version = ""
            Software = ""

        }
    }
}

$results | export-csv -Path "C:\stairway\toheaven.csv" -notypeinformation
```